# Expand NSOutlineView item on single click anywhere in row

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

What is the most expedient way to expand NSOutlineView rows on a single click of the entire row? (not the disclosure triangle)

Is there a single setting for this? Or some magical mode setting that changes the behavior similar to source list style?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplest way to do **both** expand *and* collapse together seems to be target/action with single clicks.  I had tried overriding the selection functions in the outlineview delegate, and that worked for expansion but not collapse.  Code below for single click expand/collapse:

```
[self.myOutlineView setTarget:self]; // Needed if not done in IB
[self.myOutlineView setAction:@selector(outlineViewClicked:)];
[self.myOutlineView setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone];

- (void) outlineViewClicked:(NSOutlineView*)sender
{
    id clickItem = [sender itemAtRow:[self.itemsOutlineView clickedRow]];
    if (clickItem)
    {
        BOOL optionPressed = (([[NSApp currentEvent] modifierFlags] & NSAlternateKeyMask) == NSAlternateKeyMask);

        [sender isItemExpanded:clickItem] ? 
            [sender.animator collapseItem:clickItem collapseChildren:optionPressed] :
            [sender.animator expandItem:clickItem expandChildren:optionPressed];
    }
}
```

Expanding that to collapse siblings:

```
- (void) outlineViewClicked:(NSOutlineView*)sender
{
    id clickItem = [sender itemAtRow:[self.itemsOutlineView clickedRow]];

    if (!clickItem)
        return;

    BOOL optionPressed = (([[NSApp currentEvent] modifierFlags] & NSAlternateKeyMask) == NSAlternateKeyMask);

    // Collapse the sibling nodes (tree controller type NSTreeNode)
    for (NSTreeNode* node in ((NSTreeNode*)clickItem).parentNode.childNodes)
    {
        if (node != clickItem && [sender isItemExpanded:node]) 
            [sender.animator collapseItem:node];
    }

    [sender isItemExpanded:clickItem] ? 
        [sender.animator collapseItem:clickItem collapseChildren:optionPressed] : [sender.animator expandItem:clickItem expandChildren:optionPressed];
}
```

The `optionPressed` BOOL and the subsequent use in `expandChildren` and `collapseChildren` was suggested by @ben-haller, who noted that "an option-click on the disclosure triangle expands or collapses all of its contained items." (Quoted from [About Outline Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OutlineView/Articles/AboutOutlineViews.html)) Ben's modification extends that option-click behavior to the "anywhere in the row" methods here.

Comment: @ben-haller suggested that `[self.myOutlineView setTarget:self]` is necessary as well.   I believe that's true if there is no target-action configured in IB.  As I didn't need it, I must have done some **not** programmatic target-action from the outline view to itself in IB.   I did add the line for completeness.  Thanks, Ben.

Answer (score 1):

Swift version:

```
outlineView.target = self
outlineView.action = #selector(outlineViewClicked(_:))

@objc private func outlineViewClicked(_ sender: NSOutlineView) {
    expandOrCollapseRow(outlineView: sender)
}

private func expandOrCollapseRow(outlineView: NSOutlineView) {
    if let clickedItem = outlineView.item(atRow: outlineView.clickedRow) {
        if  outlineView.isItemExpanded(clickedItem) {
            outlineView.animator().collapseItem(clickedItem)
        } else {
            outlineView.animator().expandItem(clickedItem, expandChildren: true)
        }
    }
}
```